# cannot babel transform .marko files with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, marko

i have a working marko setup for my widget. Im using webpack 4 and babel 7. When i add babel-loader to .marko files, the webpack compiler throws because it couldn't recognize marko's syntax as valid javascript. However the loader should work after the marko transpilation.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Volumes/Workspace/product-curator-widget/src/index.marko: A class name is required (1:6)

> 1 | class {
    |       ^
  2 |   onCreate () {
```

index.marko

```
class {
  onCreate () {
    this.state = {
      items: [ {label: 'foo'}, {label: 'bar'} ] 
    }
    const pr = new Promise((resolve) => resolve()) //trying to transpile this arrow function
  }
}


<paper>
  <chip for (item in state.items) label="${item.label}" value="${item.value}" />
</paper>
```

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = () => ({
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
  entry: [
    'core-js',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.marko'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.test\.js$/],
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.marko$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.test\.js$/],
        use: ['@marko/webpack/loader', 'babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
})
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)

  return {
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "ie": "10"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaders in webpack are evaluated from [right to left](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration).  In this case, you'll want `@marko/webpack/loader` to be the first loader to run (put it last in the array), so by the time `babel-loader` is called, the `.marko` file has been compiled to JS.

*Side note: if you're using Marko components that have been published to npm, you don't want to ignore `node_modules`.  Marko recommends publishing the source `.marko` files because the compiler produces different output for the server vs the browser.  Additionally, the compilation output can be different depending on the version of Marko your app is using.*

```
      {
        test: /\.marko$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', '@marko/webpack/loader'],
      },
```

Comment: thanks alot for clarification. While this indeed doesn't break the compiler, the marko still wont be transpiled by `@babel/present-env`

in this case my `babel.config.js` is definetly loaded but doesn't transform `const` or `arrow functions `. ive edited the original post for my babel config